# Nav on top of background img

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put my navigation bar on top of my background image, and I would like to know what is the best and cleanest way to do so using the code below, here is my code:

```html
<body>
     <header>
         <div class="home_page">  
             <div class="header">
                 <h1 class="title">The Best Coffee Shop in Chicago</h1>
                 <h2 class="sub_title">Life Is Too Short For Bad Coffee</h2>
                 <h1 class="home_nav_line"></h1>
             </div>
             <figure>
                <img src="home_coffee_img.jpg" height="100%" width="100%" alt="Coffee Beans" style="height:100%;">
             </figure>
         </div>
     </header>
     <!--Menu-->
     <element class="zoom">
         <ul class="col-sm-8"><!--Screen size of menu-->
             <li> <a class="active" href="index.html">HOME</a></li><!--The active class means it will tell the user what page they are on-->
             <li> <a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
             <li> <a href="news.html">NEWS</a></li>
             <li> <a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li> 
         </ul>
     </element>
 </body>
```

Comment: is `<img src="home_coffee_img.jpg"` your background image? If yes, why don't you assign it as CSS `background-image` of `body` or some other parent element?

Comment: Thank you for your help! I figured it out based on your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your the image as a background image using css. Apply it to the element that is wrapping the header and the navigation elements, in this case that would be `body`.

```
body {
   background-image: url(YOUR_IMAGE_PATH)
}
```

See the example in the code snippet.

```css
body {
  background-image: url(https://static.independent.co.uk/s3fs-public/thumbnails/image/2018/04/15/16/china-coffee-cup.jpg?w968h681);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="home_page">
      <div class="header">
        <h1 class="title">The Best Coffee Shop in Chicago</h1>
        <h2 class="sub_title">Life Is Too Short For Bad Coffee</h2>
        <h1 class="home_nav_line"></h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <!--Menu-->
  <element class="zoom">
    <ul class="col-sm-8">
      <!--Screen size of menu-->
      <li> <a class="active" href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
      <!--The active class means it will tell the user what page they are on-->
      <li> <a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
      <li> <a href="news.html">NEWS</a></li>
      <li> <a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
  </element>
</body>
```